# UILabel with no word wrapping

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel that I want to clip text on a line basis. Or, a label in which it does **not** wrap unless I discretely pass in a "\n"

Here is code that I am currently working with:

```
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 200))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" + "\n" + "1234567890123456789"
    label.lineBreakMode = // None seem to accomplish what I am looking for
```

So this would have a label with exactly two lines of text, with each line clipping the end of the text.

Is this possible to do without having to a subview for each line?

Answer (score 0):

That's a really interesting requirement you are looking for. Unfortunately, I don't think that natively Apple supports "removing" the option for word wrapping. You will need to use a label for each line, use .byTruncatingTail, and limit the numberOfLines to 1 (default). Don't use 0 (From apple's quick help: "To remove any maximum limit, and use as many lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0").

You might find some third party code through CocoaPods/etc. to help expedite it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do this:

*Note: Swift 3 Code.*

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 20, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label.text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" + "1234567890123456789"
label.sizeToFit()

view.addSubview(label)
```

The output should be similar to:

[image]

Hope that is the general solution for your case.

Comment: This is a neat solution others may like, but I needed it so that if the first line (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP) exceeds the width of the frame, then be truncated. So that In my example, the possible maximum number of lines would be 2.